# Email Sending Application Error Question - Using Fuel SDK

Tags: fuel-sdk

Using a multi threaded application to send triggered send emails using the Fuel SDK.  We have sent thousands in small batches with no problem however today when sending a large batch ran into an issue where one some would go through fine then a set would get the error below. It would send say 1000 and then 300 would get the error and repeat (numbers change each time).  Please note the error is truncated as we did not have the column wide enough (since fixed).  Out of an 18K send about 4K failed with the error.  Any thoughts on why it might be returning a 401 for only some of the sends?  Same Exact Target account, triggered send, etc. just received the error in batches.  Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

*The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at FuelSDK.ET_Client.refreshToken(Boolean force)     at FuelSDK.Pos*

Comment: The following was provided by the Exact Target Support Team...

Comment: When a multi-threaded server-to-server app attempts to use refresh tokens, it can run into issues due to token caching which happens on the MC side. When a token is requested, if a duplicate token request comes in within a few seconds then it will provide the same token which includes the same one-time use offline(refreshtoken). In a MT process, if 2 threads happen to get the same token due to caching, it will work until it needs to refresh. After refreshing with the offline (refreshtoken) then it will prevent the other threads from refreshing with the same one and results in a 401 error.

Comment: And they did update the C# Fuel SDK to address this....